# Postgresql 9.3: changing the value of SYSTEM parameters like log_lock_waits

Tags: postgresql

I am getting following error on ALTER SYSTEM query

```
db_live=# ALTER SYSTEM SET log_lock_waits To on;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SYSTEM"
LINE 1: ALTER SYSTEM SET log_lock_waits To on;
```

I also tried changing the value in postgresql.conf and restarting the server, but it is not being reflected in SYSTEM variables when I run 'SHOW ALL'. It is happening for all other SYSTEM parameters too.

Comment: I mean 'Same issue for all other SYSTEM paramaters too'.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER SYSTEM` was introduced in 9.4, so it is [not available in 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-commands.html)

The only way in 9.3 (or earlier) to change such a setting is to edit `postgresql.conf` and the reload the configuration (using [`pg_ctl reload`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pg-ctl.html#APP-PG-CTL-DESCRIPTION))

If you don't know where your `postgresql.conf` is, you can run the following statement as a superuser:

```
select setting
from pg_settings
where name = 'data_directory';
```